# How to handle memory in galleryview in android?

Tags: android, android-gallery

In my application i have two gallery views. whenever in my gallery images increases I am getting outofmemory exception.How i can handle the memory.please can any one help me?

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to first create a thubnails of images.

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

Use lazy loading concept

> [here is the code of lazy loading that worked great for me](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Can you please provide any example.

Answer (score 1):

Like Stacks28 suggested, use lazy loading concept. Additional to this, always do `recycle()` to your images and if you are still having troubles, add this in your manifest inside application tag : `android:largeHeap="true"`

[here is an image loader example](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-lazy-image-loader-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you have many bitmaps that you are doing lots of operations with loading them in memory and not freeing the memory

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
system.gc();

Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Comment: where i can use these methods.

Comment: Wherever you are handling with the images, like showing the images in UI.